# UINavigation push creates SIGABERT issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios4

I am facing a problem Please let me out.In My app i'm using navigation on table selection i'm simply sending details of one field into another view but i don't know why i'm getting Sigabert error in it.
And it is also not giving me any reason in console even when i'm enabling Zoombies.

Please let me know the solution if you have any suggestion for me.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    MyDealDetailViewController *mydeal=[[MyDealDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyDealDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

//This arrayForGetDeal have values that are fetched from database.

  mydeal._getDealObject=[_arrayForGetDeal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//on the below line i am getting SIGABERT.

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:mydeal animated:YES];

 [mydeal release];

}
```

Comment: please comment this line mydeal._getDealObject=[_arrayForGetDeal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and then check it

Comment: comment that passing object statement and try weather it works or not.

Comment: make sure the name of nib file is `MyDealDetailViewController`

Comment: i have commented _getDealObject=[_arrayForGetDeal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; and also checked XIB name but still getting the same problem. :(

Comment: remove the release line from code and use autorelease in init method.Ok the navigation controller is there and is having a valid memory ?

Comment: i have use it but still it gives same issue on "  [self.navigationController pushViewController:mydeal animated:YES]; "

Comment: log the navigationcontroller instance and comment it here,Also check the viewdidload otf the VC you are creatn=ing.The issue may be an outlet missing it connection . **Remove outlets of the newVC and connect again**

Comment: all are connecte and on printing navigation i am getting this:self.navigationController=( "<MyDaelsViewController: 0xac44d00>" –

Answer (score 0):

Please put this line   `mydeal._getDealObject=[_arrayForGetDeal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` in comment, then check you are facing the same issue. if `YES` then there is something wrong with XIB (Binding issue, XIB Name issue).Please check all binded UIControl again.

Comment: is i need to check binded uicontrol of that class also in which i want to go on table selection?

Comment: No need to check table selection class, just check in MyDealDetailViewController class XIB.

Comment: but it is not even detecting view will appear of MyDealDetailViewController class.So whether any unbinding will be the reason for the coming issue?

Comment: Yes , when XIB will invoke and issue will found in XIB as I said like binding issue, then it will create issue. It will not load your controller.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not of your push navigation controller but actually is a **Memory Issue** arising due to 
 `mydeal._getDealObject`. The object is not getting memory if you put on breakpoints and check  line by line on the `mydeal._getDealObject=[_arrayForGetDeal objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` line you will see that the object is not having any memory. Check and see why you are getting this issue. And once any memory will be provided to the ***mydeal*** object, your crash would stop.

Comment: But if i am printing mydeal object it gives me this : _myDeal=<MyDealDetailViewController: 0x9f6e3a0> .This means it have some memory.

Comment: _getDealObject is this variable valid ?

Comment: if i am commenting that line still it gives the same issue

Comment: Then there can be only one issue , Check if Your XIB is connected to the controller.

Comment: all are connecte and on printing navigation i am getting this:self.navigationController=(
    "<MyDaelsViewController: 0xac44d00>"

Comment: since morning i'm working on it and now i am finally pushed to detail View but the main problem is : on detailView i need to show mapview also but when i'm adding mapView to it then again it shows SIGABERT ...and if i remove mapView it gets pushed to next view.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not of your push navigation controller but actually is a Memory Issue

please make the @property(nonatomic ,retain)NSArray *_getDealObject other class other wise you can enable NSZombies in your xcode